# Login view - Login button is not disabled initially based on CanLogin value, untill we click it for the first time.

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I just started looking into Caliburn Micro 2.0.0 and I started up with a simple login page implementation. 
 My page xaml looks like this

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Login name"
                       Width="100"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="LoginName" 
                     Width="200" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Password" 
                       Width="100"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Password" 
                     Width="200" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Login" 
                Content="Submit"
                Width="100"
                Margin="2"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

And my view model class looks like this

```
  public class LoginViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string loginName;
    public string LoginName
    {
        get
        {
            return loginName;
        }
        set
        {
            loginName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LoginName);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanLogin);
        }
    }

    private string password;
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Password);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanLogin);
        }
    }

    public bool CanLogin
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoginName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password);
        }
    }

    public void Login()
    {

    }
}
```

I am not sure if there are any mistakes in this. 
 But until I click the login for the first time, the login button is always enabled.

And interestingly when I work with calibur 1.5 it works perfectly....

Please help me fix this.

Comment: I've seen something similar, but tell me... is the `Button` *actually* disabled, but just *looks* enabled, or is it *actually* enabled and if you click on it, it works?

Comment: When the form initially loads the button should be initially disabled, where its actually enabled. When user clicks, it is invoking its binded action wherein I needed to check for CanLogin inside Login method now as shown   
  
    public void Login()
        {
            if (CanLogin)
            {
               
            }
        }

And from then on it works as it should.

Comment: Is your CanLogin property getter called upon form load (when debugging)?

Comment: No.......... I am wondering why.... It will be called first when we click the button for the first time....

Comment: Very strange, where is your `LoginViewModel` instantiated? Is it hosted in another `ViewModel` that inherits from a `Conductor`, or a `Screen`?

Comment: There is no screens and conductors right now. I am working with a very basic example. My viewmodel just inherits propertychangedbase.

Comment: I've just tried recreating your problem with 2.0.0 and saw the button disabled on launch. Could post a repo somewhere with the full solution illustrating the issue?